# How do I get the location data of a Twilio IncomingPhoneNumber using the REST API

Tags: api, twilio, phone-number, postal-code

In the Twilio API, when searching `AvailablePhoneNumber`s, I get all sorts of location data (such as LATA, PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude, etc).

Once I buy the number and query it through the `IncomingPhoneNumber` resource, this data is no longer available.

How can I access this information for a number I have already purchased?

Comment: Had you added address to the number while registering ? check this it has address parameter with possible values - https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers

Comment: As far as I can tell that information is not available for a previously-purchased number. We have now started capturing that information, at purchase time, in a database table.